# Emergency mode after resizing Windows 10 partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, backup, boot-repair, restore

I was running out of space on my root partition, so I made a backup with the default Ubuntu backup software to my second HD. After resizing the windows partition I get the following errors:

```
[   1.123158] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
[   1.123204] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
[   1.206041] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[   1.768668] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   1.911549] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   1.912823] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs,
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or ^D to try again to boot into dafault mode.
Press Enter for maintenance (or press control-D to continue):
```

I tried to boot a live-USB and doing boot repair. I also tried restoring the backup I made through the live-USB, selecting the backup location: "/media/2TB_HDD/Backup/Ubuntu" but this gives me the following error:

```
storage location not available, waiting for Google
```

Comment: Did you resize your Windows partition using Windows Disk Management app, or gparted in Ubuntu? Windows NTFS partitions should always be resized from Windows.

Comment: I resized with MiniTool Partition Wizard Home. Directly after I couldn't boot anymore. I tried moving the swap, / , and /home partitions but that didn't work either. I re-installed Ubuntu but I'm unable to restore my backup through backups (Déjà Dup).

Comment: It seems the problem was in Déjà Dup you have to fill in the path to restore twice. As described here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384934

Comment: The Déjà Dup is worthy of a separate question so I would [edit] it out and then ask a new question.  Then leave a comment here with a link to the new one mentioning @Fabby

Comment: You're right! I'll flag this post as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tpm error is probably from the "Trusted Platform Module" chip.

A Trusted Platform Module (TPM) is a specialized chip on an endpoint device that stores RSA encryption keys specific to the host system for hardware authentication. Each TPM chip contains an RSA key pair called the Endorsement Key (EK). The pair is maintained inside the chip and cannot be accessed by software.

The PKCS error probably has to do with Nvidia drivers being out of date, or not "signed".

Try turning off `Secure Boot` in your BIOS, and see if it solves one/both errors. Otherwise, if you can find a way to turn off the TPM chip in your BIOS, that'll take care of the first errors (but may cause a problem in Windows... you'll have to check).

Comment: Secure boot was already off. I also upgraded my BIOS firmware from 305 to 315 (ASUS N580VD) this did not solve the problem. I re-installed Ubuntu that solved the booting problem but I still can't restore my backup with the stock backups (Déjà Dup) app.

Comment: Those are two questions in one question.  Your original question has been answered and you should ask another question for Déjà Dup separately and provide more information: How did you make the backup, what are the contents of `/media/2TB_HDD/Backup/Ubuntu`, ...  @Denisuu

Comment: Yes you are right! I will flag this post as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my ASUS N580VD laptop's BIOS driver from 305 to 315 and reinstalled Ubuntu, this solved the emergency-mode problem.

The not being able to restore the backup was a simple fix as described here.

[Deja Dup Restore fails: "No backups to restore"](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2384934)

Still my backup won't restore I get the following error:

```
Invalid data - SHA1 hash mismatch for file:
duplicity-full.20181226T212031Z.vol4.difftar.gz
Calculated hash: 3c96aadf1c412a565da07f4b18d78751e8156bd1
Manifest hash: bb3d25292c63a9110c83c525e003bc752f4eac86
```

Luckily I have the habit of storing everything on a separate drive and I was able to extract the files I needed from a live-USB. I'll use Rsync or Clonezilla next time!

Thanks for the help guys!