# Restore root from SquashFS or TAR

Tags: dual-boot, backup, data-recovery, tar, squashfs

I'm running a dual-boot Ubuntu & Windows 10 Pro configuration. Before re-installing Windows I made 2 full backups with TAR and SquashFS of / with the following commands:

SquashFs:

```
sudo mksquashfs / /media/dennis/Backup_SSD/Ubuntu_N580VD_Backup.sqsh -e media dev run mnt proc sys tmp
```

TAR:

```
sudo tar czf /media/dennis/Backup_SSD/Ubuntu_N580VD_Backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/dev --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/lost+found /
```

[squashfs_log](https://pastebin.com/jPwTpj9f) and [tar.gz_log](https://pastebin.com/hAmb5Cv5)

After re-installing Windows Ubuntu failed to boot:

```
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x201] vs fed40080 f80
Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

So I re-installed Ubuntu on sda6 and now it's booting again. But how do I replace the content of the fresh install on partition sda6 with the content of my .tar.gz or .squashfs backup files?

```
sda            238.5G                                   
├─sda1 ntfs      499M | Recovery
├─sda2 vfat      100M | Boot (EFI)                                  
├─sda3            16M | Microsoft reserved                                
├─sda4 ntfs    137.4G | Windows                                  
├─sda5 swap        4G | SWAP                          
└─sda6 ext4     96.5G | Ubuntu
```

Comment: Thanks! After setting up all my preferences I made a backup of sda2 (boot) and sda6 (root) with Clonezilla this turned out to be only 5,7GB so it's a very good method to make backups!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Here it is not necessary to update your post when your problem has been solved. Instead, the answer counter will be filled in with a particularly nice shade of green. :)

Comment: @Denisuu: CloneZilla is perfect to make cold system backups (`/boot` and `/` if on separate partitions, *but a bad system for data files.  I use `borgbackup` but `backintime` and `dejadup` are good as well and were my previous data backup programs`) `borgbackup` is a compressing *deduplicating* backup program, and a PPA was created a short while ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your logs, you made a hot system backup instead of a cold system backup, which means that files were being modified while you were making your backup.  On top of this, your OS (`/`) and data (`/home`) are not separated, so under these, far from ideal circumstances, I would:

1. log into the console [as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login), not the GUI nor your admin user
2. Mount the squash file system:

   ```
   mkdir /media/restore
   mount /media/dennis/Backup_SSD/Ubuntu_N580VD_Backup.sqsh /media/restore -t squashfs -o loop
   ```
3. Copy your data:

   ```
   cp --recursive --preserve=all /media/restore/home/* /home/
   ```
4. Shut down the machine in its working state
5. Take a [CloneZilla live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) cold backup of your system in its current state.

**For the following steps, it'll depend on your luck and the kind of applications you were running at the time you made the hot backup.**

5. Copy everything from your hot backup except `/run` which is a virtual file system set up in memory by the kernel:

   ```
   rsync --archive --verbose --progress /media/restore/* / --exclude /media/restore/run
   ```
6. Reboot and pray to the gods of Torvalds and Stallman that this'll work.  **¯\_(ツ)_/¯**
7. If it doesn't work:

   1. Restore your CloneZilla Live cold backup
   2. Reinstall all your applications.  (Individual configurations of these applications are still available in your `/home` from the data restore.)
   3. For heaven's sake: don't take hot system backups and [put the CloneZilla Live ISO file in your grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025656/how-do-i-boot-an-iso-file-from-my-drive-using-grub2-on-uefi-machines) and take cold backups from now on.
8. If it does work: [Remove root login please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login).  ***Congratulations!***  I never thought you would reach this step as hot backups are notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Please don’t use emoticons or emojis on Ask Ubuntu, [that’s considered noise by the community](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18354/507051).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I'll just start from scratch then, there's really not much important in there. It was just meant as a clean install + apps & configurations backup. I actually tried to make a backup with Clonezilla before I did the .tar and .squashfs backups. But got an error: `The partition table in this disk is illegal/invalid: /dev/sda It's not supported by parted. Parted is used in Clonezilla to parse the filesystem in the partition table. This partition table is detected as WRONG by parted!`

Comment: I'm just looking for a good way to make a full system backup that is also compressed. I will add Clonezilla to grub as you described and try again. Can I make a backup of the bootloader too? Because the problem described [here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/after-upgrade-to-mate-18-04-boot-problems-not-trusted-key/16713) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105177/emergency-mode-after-resizing-windows-partition-cant-restore-backup) always keeps coming back. Thanks again and happy NY!

Comment: @dessert  as per your link: "So no, please don't include emojis in AU questions or answers ***unless they really are necessary for some reason.***" [Emphasis mine].  As Linus and RMS are not really gods, the emoji conveys emphasis and *is therefore necessary*  **;-) :D**

Comment: @Denisuu Yes: CloneZilla even allows copying the empty sector between the boot sector and the first partition, which is sometimes used by copy-protected programs to store data.  On the error: you have a corrupted partition table and should not try to restore that: create anew (as you already did)